# Show keyboard without animation?

Tags: android

I want to know whether I can show the keyboard without animating it up.

TL;DR:
I have a view that adjusts its sizing to the area available (that is, area above the keyboard). The view I come from already has the keyboard up. The view that I just navigated to also has the keyboard, but now the view content animates up, even though there's no keyboard. How can I eliminate the animation, and still show the view centered above the keyboard, no matter the device size?